# Left join in MySQL doesn't give me expected result

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT t.teilnehmer_id, t.familienname, t.vorname, t.ort, t.ortsteil, t.kontrolle_ertrag, t.kontrolle_1j, t.kontrolle_brache,
     SUM(fe.nutzflaeche) AS nutzflaeche_ertrag, GROUP_CONCAT(fe.nutzflaeche) AS einzelfl_ertrag,
     SUM(fp.nutzflaeche) AS nutzflaeche_pflanzj, GROUP_CONCAT(fp.nutzflaeche) AS einzelfl_pflanzj,
     SUM(fb.nutzflaeche) AS nutzflaeche_brache, GROUP_CONCAT(fb.nutzflaeche) AS einzelfl_brache,
     SUM(fn.nutzflaeche) AS nutzflaeche_nicht_aush, GROUP_CONCAT(fn.nutzflaeche) AS einzelfl_nicht_aush
 FROM  teilnehmer t
 LEFT JOIN anrede a ON (t.anrede_id = a.anrede_id)
 LEFT JOIN antragsform af ON (t.antragsform_id = af.antragsform_id)
 LEFT JOIN bank b ON (t.bank_id = b.bank_id)
 LEFT JOIN flurverzeichnis fe ON (t.teilnehmer_id = fe.teilnehmer_id AND fe.kulturbez = 'E')
 LEFT JOIN flurverzeichnis fp ON (t.teilnehmer_id = fp.teilnehmer_id AND fp.kulturbez = 'P')
 LEFT JOIN flurverzeichnis fb ON (t.teilnehmer_id = fb.teilnehmer_id AND fb.kulturbez = 'B')
 LEFT JOIN flurverzeichnis fn ON (t.teilnehmer_id = fn.teilnehmer_id AND fn.kulturbez = 'N')
 WHERE 1 = 1
 GROUP BY t.teilnehmer_id
 ORDER BY familienname, vorname
```

The sum doesn't reflect the correct areas if there is a match in more than one kulturbez. E.g. if I have 5 rows with kulturbez 'E' and 2 rows with kulturbez 'N', each 'E' row shows up twice and each 'N' row shows up 5 times. Any suggestions on how to redo the SQL to only sum each row with the matching kulturbez once?
Thanks,

Gunter

Comment: To solve this problem, you will need to aggregate the tables *before* doing the `join`.  That is how you avoid a Cartesian product.

Comment: Pretty much any time you have mulitple 1:N relationships involved, your aggregate calculations will need to be performed in subqueries.

Comment: This is how `LEFT JOIN` works, you should get 2x5 records in the result set.

Comment: Alternatively, if the joins to `flurverzeichnis` are the only 1:N joins, you can maybe replace the multiple joins with conditional aggregation. Answer incoming...

Comment: You might want to put together a working sample at http://sqlfiddle.com if Uueerdo's solution doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, unavoidable 1:N joins usually need subqueries to calculate aggregate values appropriately; but it looks like your need can be solved with conditional aggregation, like so:

```
SELECT t.teilnehmer_id, t.familienname, t.vorname, t.ort, t.ortsteil, t.kontrolle_ertrag, t.kontrolle_1j, t.kontrolle_brache
    , SUM(CASE WHEN f.kulturbez = 'E' THEN f.nutzflaeche ELSE NULL END) AS nutzflaeche_ertrag
    , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN f.kulturbez = 'E' THEN f.nutzflaeche ELSE NULL END) AS einzelfl_ertrag
    , SUM(CASE WHEN f.kulturbez = 'P' THEN f.nutzflaeche ELSE NULL END) AS nutzflaeche_pflanzj
    , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN f.kulturbez = 'P' THEN f.nutzflaeche ELSE NULL END) AS einzelfl_pflanzj
    , SUM(CASE WHEN f.kulturbez = 'B' THEN f.nutzflaeche ELSE NULL END) AS nutzflaeche_brache
    , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN f.kulturbez = 'B' THEN f.nutzflaeche ELSE NULL END) AS einzelfl_brache
    , SUM(CASE WHEN f.kulturbez = 'N' THEN f.nutzflaeche ELSE NULL END) AS nutzflaeche_nicht_aush
    , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN f.kulturbez = 'N' THEN f.nutzflaeche ELSE NULL END) AS einzelfl_nicht_aush
FROM  teilnehmer t
    LEFT JOIN anrede a ON (t.anrede_id = a.anrede_id)
    LEFT JOIN antragsform af ON (t.antragsform_id = af.antragsform_id)
    LEFT JOIN bank b ON (t.bank_id = b.bank_id)
    LEFT JOIN flurverzeichnis f ON (t.teilnehmer_id = fe.teilnehmer_id)
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY t.teilnehmer_id
ORDER BY familienname, vorname
```

Aggregate functions ignore NULL values for the most part. *(Also, technically `ELSE NULL` is optional, as it is the assumed value if `ELSE` is not specified; but is good practice to make your intent clear.)*